# generic base class that implements interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

How can I declare my Basepage class in an asp.net webforms project to also implement IBasePage?

```
public abstract class BasePage<T> : Page where T : class
{

}
```

and the interface

```
public interface IBasePage
    {
        UserProfile UserProfile { get;}
        bool IsStreamingAdmin {get;}
        int? EmplId {get;}       
    }
```

my ultimate goal is to be able to write code this like:

```
IBasePage page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as IBasePage;
if (page.IsStreamingAdmin)
{
    //do something here....
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question isn't totally clear to me, but couldn't you just do:

```
public abstract class BasePage<T> : Page, IBasePage where T : class { }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class BasePage<T> : Page, IBasePage where T : class { }
```

If your class implements all the methods defined in the `interface` your code is able to compile and you will be able to call an `instance` of your abstract class.

Calling `page.IsStreamingAdmin` will result in returning the value of the class you have an instance of.

Comment: why would you post the identical piece of code as someone who answered 10 minutes before you and recieved many upvotes, surely you could have just posted your little bit as a comment if you had something to add to an exact answer?

Comment: I was trying to tell him how to achieve what he was after. Because I would like that if I had a question. And yes, I could have posted it as a comment.

Comment: ok, i +1ed you to remove the -1 someone gave you because it does answer the question, despite being duplicate

Comment: Thanks. This was my very first answer ever. You have to start somewhere.